# Should/Can I organize data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, architecture

Should I organize data in my React app or have it organized before react accesses the data?

I currently have an app that gets data from an API, in this case a list. I want to iterate this list and count how many items there are in each value range. The final goal is to create a histogram. Should this data already be in the proper format before being saved to the api?

```
const Histogram = (props) => {
    const data = props.data
    const max = Math.max(...data)
    const min = Math.min(...data)

    for (var i; i<data.length; i++){
        var value = data[i]
        //logic to count how many in each value section
    const chunk1 = numberInChunk1
    const chunk2 = numberInChunk2

    //create histogram

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if your UI should compute a historgram or if you should have an endpoint that can return it already computed? I think this depends entirely on your use-case. Is it computed often? Is the computation expensive? Does the data change often? Likely many other factors to consider. Question is overly broad, please try to narrow the scope to a specific issue or aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Question is too broad but if you are asking about the application architecture than you should just follow a simple rules of the data separation and abstraction.

You API should be frontend independent and abstract as much as it's possible. Sometimes it's hard to achieve such separation because of the business needs, performance, legacy code and etc. But if you are implementing new application, than try to think what can be reused and what is strictly UI responsibility? If it's a heavy computation, than probably it's an API responsibility.

But also ask yourself a question whether you can
reuse this data in another application if it will prepared on a server side?

What if stakeholders will ask you to change react component and display this data in another format, can this lead to another change on server side?
If answer is yes, than your API is not abstract enough to handle various usecases.